# Get the Nested Array Object in datatable in mdata

Tags: jquery, datatable

Below is my the  json structure and i need to retrive the ContactRole.staffRoleDescription data in a column in datatable.
i have tried with some of the methods like `"mdata" :"ContactRole.staffRoleDescription"`. but Iam not getting the Output. If it cannot be done through normal data table syntax, how can be implemented through iterating it

```
 {
                "favoriteStatus": true,
                "favoriteId": 1,
                "name": "Jason Parker",
                "phoneNumber": "+1 987-654-3210",
                "businessRole": "Account Executive",
                "ContactRole": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "roleStatus": "internal",
                        "staffRoleDescription": "MSC"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "roleStatus": "external",
                        "staffRoleDescription": "AP (Apple Professional)"
                    }
                ],
                "email": "email@domain.com"
    }
```

Comment: try `ContactRole[index].staffRoleDescription` eg  `ContactRole[0].staffRoleDescription`

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working :

```
table = {
    "favoriteStatus": true,
    "favoriteId": 1,
    "name": "Jason Parker",
    "phoneNumber": "+1 987-654-3210",
    "businessRole": "Account Executive",
    "ContactRole": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "roleStatus": "internal",
            "staffRoleDescription": "MSC"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "roleStatus": "external",
            "staffRoleDescription": "AP (Apple Professional)"
        }
    ],
    "email": "email@domain.com"
}

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    alert(table["ContactRole"][i]["staffRoleDescription"])
}
```